# Loader auto-fades in (jQuery/javascript/Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm probably an idiot, but I can't find where's problem.

There is a "Suggest a word" button at the bottom of [this page](https://spongepie.com).

After filling out the form and clicking on send a loader shows up, however, it doesn't disappear when ajax finishes (it fades out and fades in unexpectedly).

I have no idea why it fades in again and I can't find the reason behind this.

Here is the most important piece of code (I hope so).

```
$('#suggestQuestionModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {


        var currFormGroup = 0;
        var maxFormGroups = 4;
        //while(currFormGroup < maxFormGroups) {


            $('#suggestionSend').click(function() {

                if (validator.form()) {
                $("#suggestQuestionModal .form-group").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#suggestLoading").fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#suggestionSend").attr('disabled', true);

                });

                if ($("#suggest-email").val() != '' && $("#suggest-want-mail").prop('checked'))
                    email = $("#suggest-email").val();
                else
                    email = 'NULL';
                word = $("#suggest-word").val();
                pack = $("#suggest-pack").val();
                lang = $("#suggest-lang").val();

                var request = $.ajax({
                  url: "/ajax/suggestQuestion.php",
                  method: "POST",
                  data: {word: word, pack: pack, lang: lang, email: email}
                });


                $("#suggestQuestionModal .form-group").hide().children(':input').val('');
                $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group > :checkbox').prop('checked', false);


                request.error(function(xhr,status,error) {
                $("#suggestLoading").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                  $("#suggestQuestionModal .modal-body div.alert").addClass('alert-danger').html("<?=$lg['suggest_error']?> <a class=\"alert-link reset-suggestion\"><br><?=$lg['try_again']?></a>").fadeIn('slow');
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      $('#suggestQuestionModal').modal('hide');
                      }, 10000);
                  });
                }); 

                request.success(function(result, status, xhr) {
                    if (result == "OK") {
                    $("#suggestLoading").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#suggestQuestionModal .modal-body div.alert").addClass('alert-success').html("<?=$lg['suggest_success']?> <a class=\"alert-link reset-suggestion\"><br><?=$lg['suggest_add_another']?></a>").fadeIn('slow');


                     });
                     }

                    else {
                    $("#suggestLoading").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#suggestQuestionModal .modal-body div.alert").addClass('alert-danger').html("<?=$lg['suggest_error_info']?> "+result+" <a class=\"alert-link reset-suggestion\"><br><?=$lg['try_again']?></a>").fadeIn('slow');

                    });

                    }

                    });

                    $("#suggestQuestionModal .modal-body").on('click', '.reset-suggestion', function() {
                        resetSuggestionModal();
                    });



                }


            });


                showGroups();


            function showGroups() {

            $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group > :input').on("change", function() {               
                if ($(this).parent().index() == currFormGroup) {

                if (currFormGroup < maxFormGroups) {
                    currFormGroup++;
                    $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq('+currFormGroup+')').fadeIn('slow');
                    if (currFormGroup == 4) {
                        $('#suggest-email').rules('add', {required: true, email: true});
                    }
                }



            }
            });

            }

            $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq(3) > :input').change(function() {

                    /*if ($(this).checked && $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq(4)').css('display') == 'none') {
                    alert("SHOW IT!");
                        $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq(4)').fadeIn('slow');
                        currFormGroup++;
                        alert(currFormGroup);
                    } */
                    if (!$(this).prop('checked') && $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq(4)').css('display') == 'block') {
                        $('#suggestQuestionModal .form-group:eq(4)').fadeOut('slow').children(':input').val('');
                        currFormGroup = currFormGroup - 1;
                        $('#suggest-email').rules('add', {required: false, email: false});
                    }

                    });

        //}
```

AFAIK (I tried to debug it with alerts) something bad happens right before $('#suggestionSend').click closing bracket.

BTW. Yes, I know the code is really a piece of mess.

Any help - greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would be good if you could show what have you tried so far or piece of code that you think is failing.

Comment: @jjczopek That might be difficult because it's horribly long, but I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got no idea of what happened.
Tried several times - no luck.
Then I decided to try with hide() and show() - still no luck.
After I changed it back to fadeIn() and fadeOut() - it suddenly works.
Some serious magic is going on...

**EDIT:** I've found it. I forgot that I moved fadeIn function outside of .form-group fadeOut, so from this:

```
$("#suggestQuestionModal .form-group").fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $("#suggestLoading").fadeIn('fast');
       $("#suggestionSend").attr('disabled', true); 
     });
```

I got this:

```
$("#suggestQuestionModal .form-group").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $("#suggestionSend").attr('disabled', true); 
     });
    $("#suggestLoading").fadeIn('fast');
```

Previously, fadeIn function was being called 4 times (because of those .form-group elements).

Now it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Ajax done instead

request.done(function( result) {

$( "#element" ).fadeout() ;

});

Comment: Tried that before, nothing changed though.